Как мне реализовать регистрацию и авторизацию пользователя через приложение Android на сервере Spring?
Хочу создать свой мессенджер на сервере Spring с помощью WebSoket. Нужно реализовать регистрацию и авторизацию пользователя в приложении. Залез в интернет, прочитал о Spring Security, OAuth (пишут устарел), JWT. Информация везде разрозненная и не понятно как регистрировать пользователя через мобильный клиент. Может кто пожалуйста дать ссылку на полезную литературу или просто помочь советом?
